# mssql 2016 need to move back to suspect mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I accidentedly run

```
alter database XX set emergency;
```

on a database (in "suspect" state) of my MS SQL 2016 server. Is there any possibility to undo things?

I don't want to repair the database, I just want to get out of of the "Emergency mode"

Thanks

Comment: have you specific save point in time ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14628/how-to-recover-the-suspect-mode-database-in-sql-server-2008 ?

Comment: I don't want to repair the database I just want to get out from the "emergency mode" as I accidentaly run the "alter database set emergency" command

Comment: On a non-suspect database, a simple `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ONLINE` will do it. On a suspect database, I don't know.

Comment: Correction, on a `SUSPECT` database you MUST performa repair operation.

Answer (score 0):

Run `DBCC CHECKDB` command to check the main reason of the corruption. You can possibly fix the corruption.

If the system tables are corrupt then it's restore from backup. To run this command to leave the emergency mode and put the database online.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE
```

If its not worked, To repair the corrupted database, you can also use software recovery tool As I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59054812/2118383), [SQL Database Recovery Tool Repairs](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-recovery.php), Which will be used to repair the corrupted database.,